# Getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: for using BETWEEN operator for column name `date` when using jdbcTemplate.query() method in Java

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, between

I am using MySQL DB with server version is 8.0.29. There is one table named - 'onboarding'.
The values of `date` column (with date type) has the format of 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
From the Springboot Application, my requirement is to fetch the records with range of values for `date` column. Concept used is **jdbcTemplate.query()** method and the query uses **BETWEEN** operator. But, Not sure why I am getting **SQLSyntaxErrorException**. The same query gives resultset when executed on MySQL Workbench.

Exception Message ---> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from onboarding WHERE  `date` BETWEEN '2019-02-02' AND '2021-02-02'' at line 1

Providing the SQL Table Definition & Code snippets details below

MySQL Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE onboarding (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    employee_name varchar(255),
    date date,
    email varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
```

Onboarding.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "onboarding")
    public class Onboarding {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
    
        @Column(name = "employee_name")
        private String employeeName;
        
        @Column(name = "date")
        private Date date;
    
        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;
    
        ---getters() & setter() ---
    }
```

OnboardingReportDAO.java

```
public interface OnboardingReportDAO {

    List<Onboarding> listByDateBetween(String startDate, String endDate);

}
```

OnbaordingReportDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class OnbaordingReportDAOImpl implements OnbaordingReportDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public List<Onboarding> listByDateBetween(String startDate, String endDate) {

        List<Onboarding> list = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM from onboarding  WHERE  `date` BETWEEN ? AND ? ",
                new Object[] { java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate), java.sql.Date.valueOf(endDate) },
                new RowMapper<Onboarding>() {
                    public Onboarding mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        Onboarding onboarding = new Onboarding();
                        onboarding.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                        onboarding.setEmployeeName(rs.getString("employee_name"));
                        onboarding.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
                        onboarding.setEmailId(rs.getString("email"));
                        return onboarding;
                    }
                });
        return list;

    }

}
```

JpaConfig.java

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource mySqlDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeedb");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("root");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("master#56");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Please assist with the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using 2 from inside the query

Comment: Yes, Two joining conditions are used i.e., startDate & endDate values. But not getting what is the error. I observed there is a double quote after endDate in the constructed query by Springboot.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM from onboarding  WHERE  `date` BETWEEN ? AND ? " check this query it has 2 `from` conditions. It is wrong.